# Error mocking a protected method in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, phpunit

I'm having difficulty mocking a protected method in CakePHP 2.2.5, when I change the method to public everything works fine however once it's protected I get the following error:

PDOException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'is_uploaded_file' at line 1

My Model looks something like this:

```
<?php
class Contact extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Contact';

    protected function is_uploaded_file($tmp_name) {
        return is_uploaded_file($tmp_name);
    }
}
```

My test looks like this:

```
<?php
App::uses('Contact', 'Model');
class ContactTest extends CakeTestCase {
    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->Contact = ClassRegistry::init('Contact');
    }

    public function testStub() {
        $stub = $this->getMock('Contact',array('is_uploaded_file'));

        // Configure the stub.
        $stub->expects($this->any())
            ->method('is_uploaded_file')
            ->will($this->returnValue(TRUE));

        $this->assertEquals(TRUE, $stub->is_uploaded_file('tmp'));
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Much appreciated.

Comment: The error you printed deals with some SQL problems. However from the code you wrote it appears you are trying to call a protected method out of the object scope where it isn't visible. Try to make the method public with ReflectionMethod->setAccessible() which was introduced in php 5.3.2 [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.setaccessible.php)

Comment: Thanks Igor, will take a look. On further investigation the SQL error is caused by the Model __call() method - it's attempting to query the database with $this->getDataSource()->query($method, $params, $this);

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cake. Does it expect your protected method to be in $method variable ? Please tell if making it public in the test helps.

Comment: Yes making it public makes the test pass, I mentioned that in my original question but wanted a way to keep it protected. Not sure what you mean by the $method variable?

Comment: " $this->getDataSource()->query($method, $params, $this); " the first argument in the query method is $method. What method should be there ?

Comment: I meant not to change the protected declaration to public but to keep it protected and change the access level with the help of a Reflection during test execution. The class will be intact but the test will work. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help Igor, the $method code is from an internal CakePHP class and when running it's "is_uploaded_file" hence the SQL error. Will give the reflection a whirl, may need to update PHP first though.